# Is it safe to use a Firestore auto-generated ID in place of the Firebase user auto-generated ID?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

The Firebase Authentication auto-generated ID is considerably longer than the Firestore [document] auto-generated ID.

```
y0b4UcWzyjOvstEdV4aLz6W23oh2 // Firebase Auth
rXGOCJpkccD1WzFdXyA2         // Firestore
```

I ask because I want to create the user's documents before I create the user itself and so I rely on the Firestore ID for the user's ID and plug that into the create-user function in Auth, which works fine. My question is, is this a good practice? And why is the Auth ID so much longer? Shouldn't document ID's have a bigger key space since documents almost always outnumber users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firestore auto-generated document IDs are generated in client-side code, and are therefor statistically generated to be unique.

Firebase Authentication UID are generated by server-side code, which means the server can (and does) check whether they are unique.

Both are going to be unique values though, so using either as a document ID is fine.

Comment: But authentication uses longer IDs, which is why I was puzzled.

Comment: Interesting. I'm not sure why that is, but both are going to be unique, so that should not be a reason to use one or the other. What I would consider is ease of looking up a user in your code (which typically favors using the UID) versus other use-cases of your app (such as needing to write the document before the user is signed in). For that last bit, consider using anonymous sign in initially to generate a UID before the user provides their credentials.